# Having trouble maintaining state on custom jQuery menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Check out the treatments menu on right hand side of [this](http://www.easyspacedesign.com/craig/azamay2/treatments/) website. It has a set of `<dt>` tags with an `<a>` tag and a `<ul>` list of submenu `<li>` links inside. The top level link and sumbmenu links are grouped together using the `rel` attribute.

As you can see the submenu slides down when you click the top level link. What I'm trying to do is maintain state between page loads so that if any of the links in the submenus are clicked it will stay open. I am trying to use the rel attribute to do this.

Here is my code so far, I am getting a bit confused with the logic:

```
function initMenu() {
    $('.menu ul:not(.active)').hide();

    var checkCookie = $.cookie("nav-item");
    if (checkCookie != "") {
        $('.menu').each(function () {
            var state = $(this).find('a:first-child').attr('rel');
            if (state == checkCookie) {
                alert(state);
                $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');       
            }
        })       
    }

    $('.menu > a:first-child').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var navIndex = $(this).attr('rel');
        $.cookie("nav-item", navIndex);

        $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
    });
}  

$(function() {
    initMenu();
});
```

EDIT**
I have changed the first part of the code to this in order to try and use the active class. But what its doing is opening all the ul's instead of just the ul that contains the li with the active class.

```
$('.menu ul:not(.active)').hide();

 $('.menu').each(function (){

   if ($(this).children(".active")){

       $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('normal');  
   }


 });
```

Comment: Please post your sample markup here, otherwise once the problem's solved this question ceases to be of use to others that may share your problem.

Comment: I don't see any dom elements with the class "menu" - You might be wanting #menu, but then you want #menu > li > a instead i think

Comment: Creating a jsfiddle with the needed CSS, HTML and JS might make it easier for other users to try and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** **after update of original question**

Use for the `if`

```
if ($(this).find(".active").length){
       $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('normal');  
   }
```

---

**Original answer**

One thing is with

```
if (state == checkCookie) {
    alert(state);
    $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');       
}
```

*`this`* in this context refers to `.menu` and not the `a` link.

You should change it to

```
if (state == checkCookie) {
    alert(state);
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('normal');       
}
```

---

The other is that the cookie plugin creates (by default) cookies that belong to the page that created them. So when you change a page it does not have access to a cookie created by another page.

Use [the path option](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cooki) when saving `$.cookie("nav-item", navIndex, {path: '/'});`

---

**The correct way**

It would be best though not to rely on cookies for navigation as it will become problematic when a user starts using the back button ..

You should really pass the `rel` value to the url as the hash `#relvalue` and use that instead.
(***hint***: check out [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties))

Comment: Thanks, there may be another way of doing it as the submenu links are given a class="active" when the page from the link is displayed, I could probably use that to keep parent ul open.

Comment: @user794846 indeed, that would be the best, if there is already a provision for identifying the active node..

Comment: I have changed the code on the first part of the to the following but what its doing is opening up all of ul's instead of just opening the one that contains the class. See the edit in the original question.

Comment: That worked a treat thanks. Can you just explain how the find(".active").length) is working in this situation?

Comment: @user794846 First the `.children` you were using looks for `immediate` children (*one level down*) so it would not find the `a` element inside the `ul`, so we used `.find` that looks for `descendants` (*any level down*). Second, we use the `.length` to see if it indeed found anything, because any `$(..)` call will return a jQuery object (*either empty or not*), and all objects evaluate to `true` when used as a boolean..